# I would like to create a Static wordpress page with no side bars, logo, nav menu, to use as a landing page

Tags: wordpress

Okay so I have a wordpress site that I am hosting myself. On this website, I have the blog with it's own theme plugins and other irrelevant items. I am trying to create a landing page in wordpress that will not have the nav menu, logo, side bar, or the footer. Basically I want the landing page to be a 100% customizable html page that has no wordpress components. When I researched how to achieve this, many guides show how to create the static page, and how to make it the landing page, however there are still annoying wordpress components that are littered everywhere. I want a completely custom wordpress landing page. How do I do that while still keeping my theme?

Answer (score 2):

Use a page template. In the theme folder, simply create the file 'empty.php' and then add the following to the top of that file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Some name
*/
?>
```

Then create a page in the Wordpress admin, with the page template: Some name, and then set that page as the home page in the settings.
Just add any content after that php tag and you're good to go.

Comment: the some name, is that completely a comment or do contents have significance?

Comment: You can use 'Some name' as anything, in your case, use 'Empty Page'. Then create a page, and set the page template to 'Empty Page'.

Comment: Is there a way to include the actual style and format of the theme without all the add-ons? :P

Comment: Yeah, just add the CSS file in the HTML-code :) such as <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: how can i use the default front-page.php as the Post Page

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way:

- In your theme folder, create a page named "page-yourtitle.php"
- In the WP admin, create a normal page named "yourtitle". It can be empty, just a page qith the title is enough.

Now, when you visit this page, WP will output only page-yourtitle.php

For example, site.com/yourtitle

Inside page-yourtitle, if you want to put some WP code, you will just have to add a call to get_header();

I think this should be useful for you, too: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: so I need to upload the file? and instead of displaying the post, it will accidentally display the uploaded file?

Comment: Yes, just put it the root of your theme.